# Allowing Internet traffic into DMZ using Azure Network Security Group

Tags: networking, security, azure, dmz

I am trying to create a simple DMZ using Azure Network Security Groups, using a Barracuda WAF as the public entrypoint into the DMZ, however I am having some trouble allowing internet traffic to access the Barracuda (and then be forwarded on to my Internal Load Balancer for my Application Servers).

What should I be using for the SOURCE and DESTINATION IP prefixes? I have tried:

- Source: 0.0.0.0/0 Destination: *internal IP of Barracuda*
- Source: INTERNET Destination: *internal IP of Barracuda*
- Source: *Public IP of Barracuda* Destination: *internal IP of Barracuda*
- Source: 0.0.0.0/0 Destination: *public IP of Barracuda*

I have also tried changing the priority of the entry to be 100 as well as 1000 (all others are 900 - 500).

I have removed all of the default endpoint configurations on the Virtual Machine for the Barracuda (as I have found that these seem to override the Network Security Group).

The network definitely works with the Barracuda when I don't have the Network Security Group installed, but I am wanting to use a Network Security Group to make sure I have a "secure as possible" DMZ.

### Endpoints

```
Name     | Type     | Prty | Source IP | Port | Dest IP       | Port | Protcl | Access
DMZ NSG:  
Internet | Inbound  | 100  | INTERNET  | 443  | 10.106.164.20 | 443  | TCP    | Allow
ADFS-WAP | Outbound | 900  | 10.0.20.0 | 443  | 10.0.1.10     | 443  | TCP    | Allow
Internal NSG:  
ADFS     | Inbound  | 900  | 10.0.20.0 | 443  | 10.0.1.10     | 443  | TCP    | Allow
```

Comment: Could it be worth posting the endpoints and network security group definitions you have set up?

Comment: if this is a federation setup, and you're using the Barracuda as a WAP, what's the need for the ADFS WAP? Also, since the NSGs are stateful, I would have thought you'd only need an ingress NSG. The outbound traffic would be allowed as part of any TCP connection established by the outside world. What are the addresses of your devices and are there any subnets defined in your VNet?

Comment: I am using the ADFS WAP as it provides a level of isolation from the ADFS instances (and is generally part of best practice deployments). The WAF is there to provide DDOS/script injection checks that I don't believe that the WAP can provide.

The WAP is deployed in the DMZ, the alternative would be to let the WAF send data through to my Private subnet which I don't think is a particularly secure design.

Comment: I realise that I've named the VM's in the subnet's the wrong way around in my question - I will edit it to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty new to Azure, but I'll try and help. I've done a bit of reading on NSGs, but not used them in practise.

- NSGs apply to a VM or a Subnet.
- NSGs currently only apply to the primary NIC of a VM.
- As you said, the VM endpoints are not compatible with NSGs.

If your Barracuda WAP has two interfaces, I'm not sure how that would work with NSGs. I don't think NSGs give you the flexibility you're after.

With this in mind, I would recommend having two subnets, DMZ and internal. For example, SUBNET1 could be 10.0.1.0/24, SUBNET2 10.0.2.0/24. You then apply your NSG to the subnets instead of the VMs, giving you the flexibility to add more services without creating new NSGs for each VM. You can just add entries to the existing NSGs if needed.

For the DMZ subnet you have an inbound rule that allows `INTERNET:443 -> SUBNET1:443 (10.0.1.0/24)`, and for the internal subnet you have have and inbound rule also: `SUBNET1:443 (10.0.1.0/24) -> SUBNET2:443 (10.0.2.0/24)`. The NSG are stateful, so if an inbound connection is initiated, the corresponding outbound traffic for that connection is also allowed.

Comment: If you think this is along the right lines, I'll update the answer with PowerShell examples to create the entries.

Comment: Thanks for your comment John - I'm reasonably familiar with NGS's, my problem is specifically around allowing Internet access into the DMZ subnet I have set up.

I have found a way to make it work, by setting the source port to *, however this seems like a cludge.

Comment: @Aidos It sounds like you're not allowing enough of the right kind of traffic through? Are you able to run a trace on the client to see what traffic, if any, is blocked?

Comment: SourcePort normally needs to be *, you (normally) never know what the clients use for port. I wouldn't consider that a "cludge".

Comment: @trondh good point. Duh.

Comment: @trondh thankyou - you're entirely correct. After talking to a friend of mine who does networking I find it fascinating that programmers and networking people think about the same things in VERY different ways!  Is there a way for me to give you the correct answer points?

Comment: no prob Aidos. Glad you got it working :-)